# El Capitan with Network Authentication Change Password not working

Tags: macos, network, password, active-directory

OS 10.11.4 : When trying to change password of my user i am getting the following error

The password for the account was not changed
The server is not available. Change your password when server becomes available

[image]

### Things i verified

1. I am connected to VPN
2. I rebooted and left it alone on VPN for sometime
3. i am able to ping my Active Directory Domain and Forest as mentioned in the following screenshot when i am on VPN. and it's ping the IP it should be pinging which is my AD

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbind  from AD and then binding to AD fixed my issue

### Few Pointers

1. Bind & Unbind from Directory Utility not from the Users Group > Network Account Server > Edit
2. It's the same screenshot as shown above in the question
3. We also updated the Prfer this Domain Server to a new server instead of domain.com it was a specific server name